# Will GlobalScope.launch run instantly?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

for example this piece of code:

```
repeat(1000) { index ->
    GlobalScope.launch(MAIN) {
        println(index.toString())
    }
}
```

Is it possible to print not orderly like 0 1 3 2 4... ?

Comment: What is `MAIN` here? It very much depends on this

Comment: @Joffrey It's Dispatchers.Main for android

Answer (score 4):

First, keep in mind that you should very probably NOT use `GlobalScope` in this case. It's only meant for launching coroutines that should keep running for the entire life of the application.

Also, in essence, when launching asynchronous blocks of code like this, it should not really matter to you when exactly they run. The contract is that they run concurrently with the rest of the code (at least until you `join()` the returned `Job`, if you do). If you wanted to launch multiple concurrent coroutines but get some *results* in-order, then you *still* wouldn't have to care about the order of execution of the coroutines, but just about getting the result of each one in the right place. For this you could use `map`+`async`+`awaitAll` instead of `launch`.

Thirdly, if you have suspension points (calls to suspend functions) in your coroutines, their execution will be interlaced, so the notion of running *before* or *after* other coroutines will get fuzzy.

With that in mind, let's answer the question. The execution order (and parallelism) will depend on the dispatcher you provide in the coroutine context.

- If it is Android's `Dispatchers.Main.immediate` or `Dispatchers.Unconfined`, it will execute these coroutines immediately - meaning in-order in this case, since you have no suspension points.
- If it is Android's `Dispatchers.Main`, which is single-threaded, coroutines will be "queued" on the main thread, but likely still run in-order eventually in this case. However you shouldn't rely on this as this would be an implementation detail, not an API guarantee.
- With multi-threaded dispatchers like `Dispatchers.Default` or `Dispatchers.IO`, the coroutines will be run in parallel with no order guarantees.
- `GlobalScope` on its own doesn't have a dispatcher, so if you launch coroutines without custom context like `GlobalScope.launch { ... }`, they will run on `Dispatchers.Default` which is multi-threaded and could run your coroutines in parallel with no order guarantees.
- `GlobalScope.launch(MAIN) { ... }` provides a custom coroutine context called `MAIN`. I don't know what is defined in this constant for you. If this context contains a dispatcher, then the dispatcher will decide as mentioned above. If not, `Dispatchers.Default` will be used by default by `launch`.

Comment: It's Dispatchers.Main for android. I noticed that you use the word "likely", so in some extremely bad case it will be not in-order?

Comment: I used "likely" because of my limited knowledge of the internals of this dispatcher. I believe in practice it will respect the "queuing" order of the coroutines, but I don't know if there is anything in the contract of this dispatcher that guarantees this behavior. For all I know, it could also also be reverse order, or unordered. The main point of my answer is that you shouldn't rely on this, though.

Comment: There's definitely no guarantee on the order of execution of concurrent coroutines, no matter which dispatcher you use. Even in the cases where you'll always observe ordering in practice, the guarantee is still not there. "Concurrent" means "concurrent".

Comment: *no matter which dispatcher you use* - it's part of the contract of `Dispatchers.Unconfined` that the launched coroutine is immediately run in the current call frame up to the first suspension point, but indeed that is unless you're already running in this dispatcher (in which case the nested coroutine is queued like in an event loop). This special case actually makes it a non-guarantee in general :D So I'm with you here.